# When I run the exe application, the code I wrote closes immediately before completion

Tags: console-application, exe, dev-c++

I just started learning the C language. I run the exe application, the code I wrote is immediately closed before completion.
I also wrote the getch () command, I don't know what I did wrong. There are no problems in the compiler, the console does not close immediately. However, when I run the exe application, I encounter 2 problems: 1- The code I wrote is not visible on the console, (i.e. after only a part of the code works)
2- console turns off immediately. Please help, I'm about to go crazy!

If you want to look at the exe file:https://mega.nz/#!EzhwCAQb!KOxP1w6GZbT4JoZzOIOltKdEfY03tBZJVvFlrvq-Sqg

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

printf ("Uyari: Turkce karakter kullanmayiniz ve sorulari tek kelime ile cevaplandiriniz.\n\n");

char isminiz[15];
char soyisminiz[15];
char yasiniz[3];
char mutlu[15];
char sanat[30];
char fb[20];
char kim[20];

printf ("Isminizi yaziniz: ");
scanf("%s",isminiz);
printf ("Soyisminizi yaziniz: ");
scanf ("%s",soyisminiz);
printf ("Yasiniz: ");
scanf("%s",yasiniz);
printf ("Mutluluk nedir: ");
scanf("%s",mutlu);
printf ("Peki sanat nedir desek: ");
scanf("%s",sanat);
printf ("Fb nin uykusu gelmis midir: ");
scanf("%s",fb);
printf ("\nIsim: %s - Soyisim: %s \n",isminiz,soyisminiz);
printf ("Mutluluk: %s\n",mutlu);
printf ("Sanat: %s\n",sanat);
printf ("Gelmis mi: %s\n\n",fb);
printf ("Fb seni cok seviyor dostum hayirli geceler :) \n");
printf("Devam etmek için herhangi bir tuşa basın\n");

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: In the same way when I debug, the console immediately closed, but I can't see an error?

Comment: You said, " I also wrote the getch () command" - can you please edit the question and include all the code for a [mcve]

Comment: My problem is solved. getch (); I had to add the function right after the console was closed, still thank you.